# What are important tricks about saving heavy media files in production?

Tags: python, django, file, optimization, deployment

What should I know about saving files in production? I need to save lots media which are pdf files. The only thing I know so far, is that I shall rename pdf files into my own naming system (for example by overwriting storage in django). But what else is important ?

Or that's all, just saving all files like 1.pdf,2.pdf,3.pdf,4.pdf.. in one media folder and it will work in long term without any other tricks and optimization? I am using django1.8 and python 2.7, but I guess it's very general question regarding running production server at all .

I hope it's not off topic, as far I faced the lack of information on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips:

- Follow a directory structure similar to this: `appname/%Y/%m/%d`.
- Use AWS S3, or another storage service, for your media and static files.
- Compress files to reduce size.
- Use whitenoise, or a similar package, to serve static files in production.

Note: These tips are not solely for media, but also static files.

Comment: what is the after-effect of saving files on the same droplet (for example here I am using Digital Ocean VPS), not in AWS storage. and can it be ok decision if those files are deleted when outdated, so the general number of those files will not be huge ?

Comment: It depends! If you have a couple hundreds files of 5MB each, then you can imagine that it will be quite an impact on your droplet's performance. If they are under 100 files, then I imagine it wouldn't be that bad.. but still, S3 is quite cheap and it will improve your website's speed (since the droplet doesn't need to waste resource on findings the files)

Comment: and if switching later to AWS, the only way of doing this would be manual copy of old files to AWS, or is it possible to serve from two storages ? Or is it almost impossible for not pro to switch later?

Comment: I doubt there would be any need to manually copy the old files. Especially since if you copy them one by one there is a chance of human error and something might go wrong, but I am sure you can automate the transfer. Now, using the local storage and S3 storage is surely possible. Never done it myself, so I can not tell you exactly how to do it, but it is possible!